# What is needed to mirror both an iPad and a late-2016 MacBook Pro to an HDTV (non-concurrently)?

Tags: macbook-pro, ipad, usb, hdmi, lightning

I want to be able to mirror an iPad Air and a late-2016 MacBook Pro to an HDTV. Not simultaneously, just one at a time. I know I could just get both the lightning to digital av adapter and the usb-c (thunderbolt 3) to digital av adapter, but is there a way to do it where I wouldnt need both? Like maybe a female usb-c to male lightning adapter (but it would need to be able to pass both video and audio).

If it helps reduce the amount of stuff I'd need to purchase, I already have HDMI to HDMI, HDMI to mini HDMI, and HDMI to mini DP (thunderbolt 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you happen to have an Apple TV?

If so, that would be how I'd do it, using Airplay.

If not, then any Apple TV (2nd generation and above) supports Airplay and you already have the cable (i.e. HDMI to HDMI) that you need to connect it to your HDTV.

The advantage of this is that you also get all the benefits of having the Apple TV as well, not to mention the fact you won't have your iPad or MBP tethered with a cable (or cables) to your HDTV (i.e. the mirroring happens via WiFi and you're able to have the iPad or MBP anywhere you want while mirroring).

If your question is about connecting these devices to any HDTV that you may need to connect to (i.e. not a single one at your home, but to various models in various locations) or you do not want/need an Apple TV, then I'm not aware of a single solution that will pass both video and audio from both devices, but perhaps someone else will have a solution.

**[EDIT]**

Just checked and Apple are selling [refurbished](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/FD199LL/A/refurbished-apple-tv) 3rd generation Apple TVs for $59. At that price, it'd be hard to warrant spending the money on cables and/or adaptors, unless you intend to carry them with you in your travels.

You can also buy brand new Apple TV 3 units from places like [Target](http://www.target.com/p/apple-tv-black-md199ll-a/-/A-14051076) who still have them in stock (since they've been superseded).

Comment: I dont have an Apple TV. Interesting to know it can do that, but for now trying to keep the cost down. Looks like Apple TV 3rd gen is ~$70. I guess that is better than 2 separate digital av adapters.

Comment: It doesnt have to be a "single solution". Was thinking maybe I could get something capable of doing the usb-c to hdmi connection for the macbook, then a simpler adapter of usb-c to lightning to hook on to that for when I want it for use with the ipad (or vice versa). Just wasnt sure about what to look for to make sure the full a/v signal gets adapted and not just for supplying power.

Comment: If I happen to come across anything I'll post back. In the meantime, came across some Apple TV 3 units still available at prices that _may_ interest you. I've updated my answer with links.

Comment: Looks like I'll be going the Apple TV route—Walmart has refurbished 3rd gens for $40. Thanks for the help.